# What is the systematic way of finding the period of a function composed of periodic functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example: $x(t) = cos(5t) + sin(6t) + cos(10t)$. How do I find the period of this?

I know the periods are: $2\pi/5, 2\pi/6, 2\pi/10$, but these numbers are irrational. How do I go about this?

Comment: Probably it will be the minimum common multiple of the periods. Anyway Im not sure. We can be sure that the sum of all periods is a valid period but not necessarily the minimum period of $x$.

Comment: If $f$ is periodic, then for whatever $g$ such that $g \circ f$ is defined, $g \circ f$ is periodic and must have $f$'s period. You can't say much else, because even if $g$ is periodic, it reads $f(x)$'s values which may or may not cover an interval as large as one of $g$'s periods. In other words, the periods alone say nothing about the period of the composed function.

Answer (score 1):

The period of the sum will be the least common integer multiple of the periods of each part. (By "integer multiple" I mean multiply the period by an integer to get some multiple, not that the multiple itself will be an integer. E.g., $7\pi$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.)

To see why, suppose $f(x)=a(x)+b(x)+c(x)$ where $a(x)$ has period $6$, $b(x)$ has period $2$, and $c(x)$ has period $15$. If we want $f(x)$ to complete a full cycle, then each component $a(x)$, $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ must complete a full cycle; in other words the period of $f(x)$ must be some integer multiple of $6$, $2$, and $15$. The period of $f(x)$ is also the *smallest* possible length of a complete cycle, and $\text{lcm}(6,2,15)=30$ is the smallest positive multiple of $6$, $2$, and $15$.

In your case, the periods are not integers, but they are all fractional multiples of $\pi$. The period of $x(t)$ is the smallest number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=k(2\pi/5)+\ell(2\pi/6)+m(2\pi/10)$ for some positive integers $k,\ell,m$. Multiplying both sides by $30/\pi$, we find that $30\alpha/\pi=12k+10\ell+6m$, and $30\alpha/\pi$ must be the smallest number satisfying this equation for positive integers $k,\ell,m$. That is, $30\alpha/\pi=\text{lcm}(12,10,6)=60$. Hence $\alpha=2\pi$. You can check yourself that this is an integer multiple of the periods of each summand, and you can convince yourself that in fact it is the least such multiple.